# SwiftUI - Issue with Text not filling out first line

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

How do I prevent my text from being automatically displayed on two lines, instead of  fill out the first line to the end, first. Is this a bug? Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

### **Expecting solution:**

[image]

### **This is what I get:**

[image]

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack(spacing: 18) {
                
                VStack {
                    Text("Need to add a complete sentence.")
                        .font(.subheadline)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                }
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(Color.green)
                
                VStack {
                    Text("Need to add a complete sentence.")
                        .font(.subheadline)
                }
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                .background(Color.gray)
                
            }
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
            .background(Color.yellow)
            .padding()
            
        }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/71698509/12299030?

Comment: @Asperi - Thank you. Unfortunately it does not solve my issue.

Comment: If you mean native Text then yes, because it is Text's feature.

Comment: This is just happening because it doesn't want to squeeze "complete" in there. In theory, it IS filling up the entire line before moving to the next line. Try with a shorter word to see.

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected "**Orphaned Words**" behavior of iOS.

So I would leave it like this and be happy with the result. But if you really want to prevent this, I'm afraid the only solution in `SwiftUI` is using `UILabel` with `UIViewRepresentable` and setting `lineBreakStrategy = []`

If you search `swift orphaned words`, you can learn more details about the topic.

https://medium.com/@pearsontsp/working-with-orphaned-words-in-ios-391a4a928e48

---

I wouldn't recommend but there is a hacky solution as well. Just put some extra empty spaces into your text. So swift thinks "sentence" word is not an orphan anymore:

```
Text("Need to add a complete sentence.  ")
```

Then the result will be:

[image]